# jQuery mobile: Set focus on a textbox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, focus, setfocus

I'm trying to set focus on a textbox in jQuery mobile. But it is not working. 
this is my code

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function FocusOnInput()
            {
                document.getElementById("username").focus();
            }
        </script>
```

and this is my text box.

```
<input name="username" id="textinput5"  type="text">
```

Comment: `$('#textinput5').focus();` use jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `document.getElementById("username")` when the ID is actually `textinput5`.

`document.getElementById("username").focus();` should be `document.getElementById("textinput5").focus();`

Comment: @ElShaikhaSue How exactly does it not work? It does.. http://jsfiddle.net/8z8wj/. How are you actually calling `FocusOnInput()` btw?

Comment: @ElShaikhaSue Yes but where are you actually calling the FocusOnInput() function!!

Comment: @ElShaikhaSue No, that's where the function is, you haven't called it anywhere. When do you want the input to be focused on?

Comment: whoops, I mean in the body "onload="FocusOnInput()"

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this code. The function is called when the page is loaded and is made visible:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#input:text:visible:first").focus();         
     });
</script>
```

Instead of :

```
function FocusOnInput()
{
  document.getElementById("username").focus();
}
```